# What will happen with a weapon if you scrape it? What changes?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If you scrape the sticker on a weapon, what happens to both the weapon and the sticker? Will any of the sticker or weapons receive damage/scratches? Are these purely cosmetically or does it change the actual weapon?

Comment: im begginner here. i dont know rules. sorry guys

Answer (score 2):

The Weaponskin itself **wont** get damaged, but the sticker will get damaged more and more (depends on how often you scrape the same sticker)
Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: but the skin will not damaged or anything? if you removed the stickers? nothing will happen on weapon?
i mean if you remove the sticker... the weapon will not scratched? it will be clear/clean?

Comment: the weapon will stay as it was, no scratches or anything